# Debug phone wihtout USB cable

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, usb-on-the-go, usb-host-mode, developer-options

How can I debug phone without usb cable even after phone restarts on non-rooted phone?  Right now I lose all developer options on reboot and have to reconnect otg cable.

Answer (score 0):

** How can you debug your phone ? I think It should be application..

First: For Debugging application, there is no way without usb cable (i think).
Second : Rooted or unrooted does not matter actually.
Third : If developer option is gone then you can again get it back by tapping 7 times in buildtime (Under settings/about option).

Comment: There is ADB over WiFi, but it may require root. Then you can instruct `adb` to connect to a remote device using `adb connect <ip of the phone> <port, usually 5555>`